# How to do .htaccess 301 redirect with # in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to write 301 redirection code in htaccess.
What I have tried.

```
RewriteRule ^old-url-shoes/$  new-url-shoes-abc/#div-id-shoes [R=301,NC,L]
```

This code is creating this url

```
new-url-shoes-abc/%23div-id-shoes
```

It is replacing '#' with '%23'.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following once, written and tested with shown samples.
Please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteRule ^old-url-shoes/$  new-url-shoes-abc/#div-id-shoes [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

***From documentation:***

> NE|noescape By default, special characters, such as & and ?, for
> example, will be converted to their hexcode equivalent. Using the [NE]
> flag prevents that from happening.

Also as an additional suggestion use  `^old-url-shoes/?$` `?` so it will cover cases of either url is ending with slash or not in Rules.